# Enviar email desde diferentes correos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Intento cambiar la configuración de mail para poder enviar correos desde diferentes correos, pero no funciona, en mi archivo `.env`, puse las credenciales iniciales y agarra esas, después las deje en blanco y no funciona, se supone que con la configuración nueva debería funcionar pero nada.

```
public function enviar_correo(Request $request)
{
    Config('MAIL_MAILER', "smtp");
    Config('MAIL_HOST', "smtp.googlemail.com");
    Config('MAIL_PORT', "465");
    Config('MAIL_USERNAME', "correoxd@uch.pe");
    Config('MAIL_PASSWORD', "miclave");
    Config('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', "ssl");
    Config('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', "correoxd@uch.pe");
    Config('MAIL_FROM_NAME', "Tituki");

    try {

        $cliente = Cliente::select()->where('id', '=', 1)->get();
        $correo = new EnvioCorreo($cliente[0]);

        Mail::to('bengyjar1998@outlook.com')->send($correo);




        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'correo' => $cliente[0]->email], dd(Config('MAIL_PASSWORD') ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['status' => false, 'mensaje' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que googlemail te permite cambiar el remitente?

Comment: pues solo quiero cambiar el correo de remitente. es como cambiar de cuenta en google, en codeigniter es super facil y en laravel aun no encuentro la manera

Comment: ¿Entonces en codeigniter te permite enviar con un remitente como correoxd@uch.pe usando el host smtp.googlemail.com?

Comment: si, y ya lo logre. solo era entrar a mas detalle. dejo los datos por si alguien le sirva.

Answer (score 1):

La configuración es esta. por si alguien mas le sirva.

```
    Config(['mail.mailers.smtp.username' => "correo@gmail.com"]);
    Config(['mail.mailers.smtp.password'=> "clave"]);
    Config(['mail.from.address'=> "correo@gmail.com"]);
```

Comment: ¿Entonces la explicación es que no estabas usando las claves del archivo `config/mail.php` sino las del .env?